# describing a plane in 3d space by appropriate rotation matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

A particle is moving in a circle along a plane in 3d space with the center at the origin. The Euler axis is given by $a = [a_1, a_2,a_3]^\top$. The particle circles on a plane perpendicular to Euler axis $a$. I want to find the appropriate coordinate transformation that would describe the plane in which the circle is being traced. Here is my approach:
We rotate the entire coordinate axis such that $Z$ axis intersects with the Euler axis. There is no need for translation of the coordinate axis since the circle is having origin as its center. The rotation angle $\phi$ between $a = [a_1, a_2,a_3]^\top$ and $\hat{z} = [0, 0, 1]^\top$ (unit vector along Z direction) is given by
$$
cos(\phi) = \frac{a.\hat{z}}{|a|} = a_3
\tag{1}
$$

The axis of rotation has to be orthogonal to $a$ and $\hat{z}$. Therefore the axis of rotation is given by
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \frac{a \times k}{|a|} = [a_2, -a_1, 0]^\top
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

The unit vector along the new axis is given by normalizing ($2$)
\begin{equation}
\hat{\alpha} = \frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|} = [\frac{a_2}{\sqrt(a_2^{2}+a_1^{2})}, \frac{-a_1}{\sqrt(a_2^{2}+a_1^{2})}, 0]^\top
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

We use Rotation matrix from axis and angle(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) with rotation axis given by ($3$) and rotation angle given by ($1$). The transformation matrix is given by

\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\phi+ \alpha_x^{2}(1-\cos\phi) &  \alpha_x \alpha_y (1-\cos\phi)- \alpha_z \sin\phi & \alpha_x \alpha_z (1-\cos\phi)+ \alpha_z \sin\phi \\
\alpha_y \alpha_x (1-\cos\phi)+ \alpha_z \sin\phi & \cos\phi+ \alpha_y^{2}(1-\cos\phi) & \alpha_y \alpha_z (1-\cos\phi)- \alpha_x   \sin\phi \\
\alpha_z \alpha_x (1-\cos\phi)- \alpha_z \sin\phi & \alpha_z \alpha_y (1-\cos\phi)+ \alpha_x \sin\phi & \cos\phi+ \alpha_z^{2}(1-\cos\phi)
\tag{4}
\end{bmatrix}.

where $[\alpha_x,\alpha_y,\alpha_z]$ represents the respective component along the $\alpha$ axis. Whether ($4$) is the appropriate transformation matrix?

Comment: This is a reasonable approach to rotate the $X-Y$ plane to your plane of rotation.

Comment: I want to ensure in the new coordinate system, my X -Y is along the the plane.  So Eqn. (4) represents the appropriate transformation matrix? What are the other approaches?

Comment: Yes.  To be clear, your equation will rotate a point $[x,y,0]$ to a new point $[x', y', z']$ which lies in the plane perpendicular to $a = [a_1, a_2,a_3]^\top$.  The equation that you are using is called Rodriguez formula.  You could also just construct a basis and use that to define a rotation matrix, but that may or may not be the correct solution depending on you application.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I thought I am rotating the standard coordinate axis [x,y,z] to a new coordinate system [x',y',z'] such that my new coordinate system will have X'-Y' plane along the plane of formation and normal to [a1,a2,a3] and equation(4) will do. So from your comment I did understand (4) will not do. Can I do any modification to (4) so that I can obtain what I want.

Comment: Jerry, yes, that is what your equation (4) is doing.  Did you code it up and try it on a few simple examples?  That is what I usually do with new algorithm.  Are you getting what you expect.

Comment: I coded various examples. I am getting the correct answer. Eqn.(4) is what I am looking for. Thanks for your comments and clarifications.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help